# webpack 5 / webpack-dev-server: how to serve other file then index.html

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

When i was using webpack 4 (4.44.1) with webpack-dev-server (3.11.0) i had a setting

```
 devServer: {
    index: 'other_filename.html'
 }
```

and thanks to that setting dev server was serving that file at `/` instead of index.html (which is not generated in the build process in my project).  How can i get that result with latest versions (5.73.0 / 4.9.2) as index property is not valid anymore (get a build error)? I can't really see any entry that would match that setting in latest docs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I found it:

```
devServer: {
  devMiddleware: {
    index: 'filename.html',
  },
},
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).